# Char comparison in C

Tags: c, linked-list, char

So I'm trying to do this function that adds a unit to the linked list provided that the user inputs a unique unit letter. My code compiles. But after the first run, it only says that the "unit letter already exists" even if it supposedly shouldn't yet. Can somebody please tell me just where I went wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

```
void addU(NODE** head){
    NODE *newNode, *temphead, *current;
    int check = 0;
    char ul, nl;
    newNode = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    newNode->unit = malloc(sizeof(UNIT));

    /*Get unit details*/
    printf("\n\n\tUnit Letter: ");
    scanf(" %c", &(newNode->unit->letter));
    printf("\n\tMaximum number of occupants: ");
    scanf("%d", &(newNode->unit->max));

    /*Check if unit letter is unique*/
    temphead = current = *head;
    if (temphead!=NULL){
        while (current!=NULL){
            ul = tolower(current->unit->letter);    //convert to small case for comparison
            nl = tolower(newNode->unit->letter);
            if (ul == nl){
                check=1;
                printf("\n\n\tInvalid: Unit letter already exists.\n"); 
                break;
            }else current = current->next;
    }}

    /*Add newNode to list if unit letter is unique*/
    if (check==0){
        if (*head==NULL){
            newNode->next = NULL;
            *head = newNode;
        }else{
            newNode->next = *head;
            *head = newNode;
        }
        printf("\n\n\tUnit successfully added!\n");
    }
    free(newNode);
    free(newNode->unit);
}
```

Comment: temphead = current = *head; this shouldn't  be valid

Comment: 1) Don't use all-uppercase names for anything else than macros and _enum-constants_. 2) Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C (strange enough, you casst them inconistently). 3) Time to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you insert a new node in the list, then do not destroy it immediately.